# Why do EFI distros want to be alone in a multibooting environment?

Tags: uefi, multiboot

I'm new to linux.
Currently I have 4 buntu-distros on my old Mac Leopard.
Every time I try to multiboot with more than 1 EFI distro I'm stuck with boot issues (that is I can't boot). So I go back with only buntu-distros living together on my computer.
...let alone inexplicable (to me, because I'm not an experienced user) other issues that boil down to the following:
some distros (a lot) I can't even open every time I insert my usb drive. In fact I have to say that the fail average diminished when I learned to burn a usb drive by terminal; yet a lot of KDE and fedora-distros are out of my "province").

Examples
1) Maui doesn't see my wifi, so I have to quit before start installing
2) KDEneon, SolydK, Korora, Fedora don't see my wifi, even if the installation worked "fine". 
3) Chapeau (gnome GUI) doesn't display whenever I download and burn the ISO on a usb drive (3 or more times...). Of Chackra I couldn't even see the logo from the ISO.

PS In order to get a EFI distro, I have to avoid multibooting (Manjaro KDE worked fine for some days all alone on my Mac; same story with PClinux and a lot of other distros)

I know that all the trouble is all my fault. I keep on going bacause I like linux very very much.

Comment: Regarding some of your inexplicable issues: many distros fail to see the WiFi on a Mac out-of-the-box due to the nature of the drivers for the Broadcom chipsets they tend(ed?) to use.  You seem to be trying a lot of things; does anything result in a specific error message that we might be able to help with?

Comment: As of the Broadcom chipset, I have to say that I had to tweak with the driver manager respectively with Linux Mint (Mate and KDE versions). I ticked the recommended chipset with the usb drive inserted to get the drive). The same I did with PClinux and Internet worked fine at last. I can't say anything in regard of a specific error message.